# VLOOKUP as a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in a tab with columns: street_id, street_name, street_corner_1 and street_corner_2 (a street corner is the name of the street that intersects it at the beginning or end).

So I have in another tab a table where columns go through street1 to streetn, rows work the same (like a matrix), and I want to check if the name of the street of row 1 (street1) is either the street corner 1 or 2 of street2.

What I wanted to do is format the cell so `=COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(street2;street_id:street_corner_2;{3;4}),VLOOKUP(street1;street_id:street_name;2))>0`

So, the range for the countif would be the two street corners of street2 and the criteria would be the name of street1, and the cell would be 1 if the name of street1 is among the corners of street2 and 0 otherwise.

I want to define the range with VLOOKUP, how can I do this?

Comment: Your description is very confusing. Please edit your question and post a small data sample, say 5 streets in your matrix. Then explain the desired result for your Countif and what logical rules lead to the result. VLookup cannot be used to create a range, but Index() can. So don't get all married to Vlookup as the solution, because it's not the right function. Again: Edit your question to provide these details. Do not do that in a comment. You can post a comment to alert followers of this question once you have provided the details.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I made a fake dataser including a street map to see if this what you mean. You want a matrix table with the first and last intersection and check if it's corner 1, corner 2 or nothing.

You can do it with 2 VLOOKUPS. My formula is (note I'm using mixed references so I can use same formula for all columns and rows):

```
=IF(I$1=$H2;"-";IF(VLOOKUP(I$1;$A$2:$D$5;3;FALSO)=$H2;"Corner 1";IF(VLOOKUP(I$1;$A$2:$D$5;4;FALSO)=$H2;"Corner 2";"-")))
```